# PyLance in strict mode: additional typing hints for external libraries

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

The code [Python 3.11, Visual Studio Code, Pylance strict mode]

```py
from typing import List, Tuple
import networkx as nx


graph = nx.MultiDiGraph()

# .add_edge(source node, sink node, edge type)
graph.add_edge("node1", "node2", (0, 0))
graph.add_edge("node1", "node2", (0, 1))
graph.add_edge("node2", "node3", (0, 2))

triplets: List[Tuple[str, str, Tuple[int, int]]] = []
for u, v, e_type in graph.edges(keys=True):
    triplets.append((u, v, e_type))
```

gives me three groups of PyLance warnings (shown below).

**Question:** How do I pass the message *please, trust me, `u` is `str` and `e_type` is `Tuple[int, int]`* to PyLance, so it would not complain even though, in general, `u`, `v` and `e_type` can be anything (hashable)?

---

The warnings are issued:

- for the function `add_edge`:

> Type of "add_edge" is partially unknown
> Type of "add_edge" is "(u_for_edge: Unknown, v_for_edge: Unknown, key: Unknown | None = None, > **attr: Unknown)

- for the for loop (shown for "u", same for "v" and "e_type"):

> Type of "u" is unknown

- for the append (which is a consequence of the previous warning):

> Argument type is partially unknown
> Argument corresponds to parameter "__object" in function "append"
> Argument type is "tuple[Unknown, Unknown, Unknown]"

I noticed that including `assert isinstance(u, str)` helps, but

- `isinstance` tends to be slow, so I would avoid it if possible
- I don't know, how to check that e_type is actually `Tuple[int, int]` (`isinstance` does not allow `Tuple[int, int]` as the second argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are not a maintainer of the [`networkx`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/) codebase, so you have no control over their annotations. It seems there is an [open issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3988) for adding proper annotations to the package. Until that happens, you are out of luck.

If the `Graph.edges` method is untyped, a static type checker like Pyright cannot know what it returns. Similarly, if the `add_edge` method has no parameter annotations, there is no way to check, if your arguments are of the correct type.

---

### Band-aid fixes

One workaround for the time being is to at least define the return type of `edges` in your particular case and pipe the returned value through [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast). In principle, this is how that works: (I intentionally use a generic function name here instead of `edges`.)

```py
from typing import cast


def some_untyped_function(*_args, **_kwargs):
    return [("spam", "eggs", (-1, 1))]


ReturnType = list[tuple[str, str, tuple[int, int]]]


triplets = []
for u, v, e_type in cast(ReturnType, some_untyped_function(keys=True)):
    triplets.append((u, v, e_type))
```

A few things to note here:

- When the item type of the iterator in the `for`-loop is known and all you do is append the items to an empty list (`triplets`), a competent type checker should be able to infer the type of the resulting list automatically. Adding `reveal_type(triplets)` and running the code through MyPy shows that it does. (I did not test Pyright.) This means you don't necessarily need to annotate `triplets` explicitly, but you can of course still do so for clarity.
- This is a minor thing: If you are on Python `>=3.9` (as you said you are), you can use the [generic alias types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias) for the built-in collections like `list` and `tuple` instead of `typing.List` and `typing.Tuple`.
- This code may still cause warnings because we are still calling `some_untyped_function` and in your initial code you are still calling `add_edge` and neither of those functions is annotated. MyPy has a specific setting named [`disallow_untyped_calls`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-disallow_untyped_calls), with which you can instruct it (on a file-by-file basis, if needed) to ignore untyped function calls in an otherwise typed context. I could not find the equivalent for Pyright/Pylance, but maybe you will or someone else knows.

If there is no convenient way to configure the type checker to allow untyped function calls, you can always resort to `# type: ignore` directives, so you can write something like this:

```py
...
graph.add_edge("node1", "node2", (0, 0))  # type: ignore[no-untyped-call]
```

The downside is obviously that you would have to add those to every line that has an untyped function call.

---

### Typed wrappers

If you use all of these untyped functions in multiple places and you want to avoid repeating the `# type: ignore` directives and type casting everywhere, you may be able to write your own stubs selectively or even simplified wrappers around them that just cover *your* particular use cases.

Here is a very rudimentary wrapper class around `MultiDiGraph`:

```py
from collections.abc import Hashable
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar

import networkx as nx  # type: ignore[import]

U = TypeVar("U", bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar("V", bound=Hashable)
K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)


class MyMultiDiGraph(Generic[U, V, K]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.nx_graph = nx.MultiDiGraph()

    def add_edge(
        self,
        u_for_edge: U,
        v_for_edge: V,
        key: K | None = None,
        **attr: Any,
    ) -> None:
        self.nx_graph.add_edge(u_for_edge, v_for_edge, key=key, **attr)

    def edges(self, keys: bool = False, **kwargs: Any) -> list[tuple[U, V, K]]:
        return self.nx_graph.edges(keys=keys, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
```

By making it generic you will enforce correct types for the `add_edge` method any receive correct type inferences for the `edges` method. With this setup, you would need to specify the type arguments for the class ahead of time.

Demo:

```py
graph = MyMultiDiGraph[str, str, tuple[int, int]]()
graph.add_edge("node1", "node2", (0, 0))
graph.add_edge("node1", "node2", (0, 1))
graph.add_edge("node2", "node3", (0, 2))

triplets = []
for u, v, e_type in graph.edges(keys=True):
    triplets.append((u, v, e_type))

reveal_type(triplets)
```

This should now work mostly without complaints by the type checker and the revealed type should be `list[tuple[str, str, tuple[int, int]]]`. Although different type checkers may require different ignore-directives (e.g. at the call site of `add_edge` rather than at the import).

Of course this can become unwieldy, if you use a lot of different methods because you'll have to basically rewrite wrappers for all of them. But at least you only have to do that in *one* place.

I suppose the most sustainable option would be to participate in the PRs that add type annotations to `networkx` yourself, if you plan to use that package often in the future.